# How to change 3rd letter (assembler)

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to change the third letter that user inputs with the last letter, and chnage the last letter with '*' symbol. So far, I managed to write this piece of code, which lets you input 7 symbol word:

```
a100
mov dx, 200
mov ah, 0A
int 21
mov bh, 00
mov bl, byte ptr[201]
mov byte ptr[200], 0D
mov byte ptr[201], 0A
mov byte ptr[202 + bx], 24
mov dx, 200
mov ah, 09
int 21
mov ah, 4c
int 21

a200
db 07 00 '*******'

n ivesk.com
r cx
200
w
q
```

The problem is that I am not sure how this works and what I should do next. Do you have any tips?. Maybe you can recommend good website in which all of these commands like (0A 09) would be explained?
Thanks.

Comment: For reference, 8086 code is all but useless anymore outside of a boot loader.  64-bit OSes won't run it natively, and even 32-bit ones will run it via a compatibility layer.  If you're going to mess around with assembly language, i'd highly recommend using a real debugger (like WinDbg or NTSD, which come with the Windows dev kits, which are free) and/or a real assembler (like Yasm or NASM, which are both free), and learning to write x86 (32-bit) code at least.

Comment: @cHao yes, I would, but since university is requesting me to use dosbox, I use dosbox :) I have an assigment and I only have two weeks to figure this out :) Anyway, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>(Assuming this code actually works (cause i haven't messed with 16-bit code in ages, and don't have a 32-bit OS -- much less a 16-bit one -- to test on)...)</sub>

You apparently already know that `[202+bx]` is the character right after the last char of the input, cause that's where you're putting the `$` that marks the end of the string.  Wonder what `[201+bx]` points at...?  :)

And since your buffer is at a hard-coded address, you already know where the first character is -- and thus, where the third is as well.

So, simply `mov` the last character into a register, and `mov` the register to the address of the third char.  Then set the register to '*', and `mov` the register to the address of the last char.